# Maximum number of concurrent jobs in cloud dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Is there a limit on the number of concurrent dataflow job (not cores)?
I was trying to submit ~40 small jobs to run in parallel, but started getting 429 Rate Limit Exceeded error after 7 jobs.

Thanks,
G

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a limit for the number of concurrent jobs per project.

In alpha we currently support 10 concurrent jobs. If you would like to have this limit increased during alpha please contact dataflow-feedback [at] google [dot] com.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the official document [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/service/dataflow-service-desc),

> You may run up to **25 concurrent Dataflow jobs** per Cloud Platform project.
>
> The Dataflow service is currently limited to processing job requests that are 10MB in size or smaller. The size of the job request is specifically tied to the JSON representation of your pipeline; a larger pipeline means a larger request.